# Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist

Tags: angular, npm, angular8, angular9

I updated my angular to v9 and when I try to go back in v8, I receive this error.
I have already tried the following:

- uninstall -global angular/cli
- uninstall angular/cli
- go back to my last package.json
- delete node_module folder
- delete repo

This error continues to show.

My stacktrace is :

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.
See angular-errors.log for further details.
```

angular-errors.log :

```
[error] Error: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.
    at Observable._subscribe (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental/jobs/simple-scheduler.js:350:23)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
    at /Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:22:31
    at Object.subscribeToResult (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:65:54)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:55:14)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:86:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at /Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:17:28
    at Object.subscribeToResult (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:65:54)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:55:14)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Front/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
```

ng --version :

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.18
Node: 12.15.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.13
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.18
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.1
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.18
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.18
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.18
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.1
@schematics/angular               8.3.18
@schematics/update                0.803.18
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.41.2
```

Comment: I got this error after running `npm audit fix`. Although I lock dependencies it still upgraded to angular 9 which I don't want. As always with Angular major releases, very inconvenient and a hassle upgrading. I would advise to stay on Angular 8 if not strictly necessary, a lot of dependencies are not yet updated to the latest version and will cause a lot of errors.

Comment: I did revert the changes after `npm audit fix`, then `npm i && npm update && npm audit fix && npm audit fix`. So basically did first an update and THEN audit fix. Worked for me.

Answer (score 392, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with `@angular-devkit/build-angular`..
Try downgrading it to a specific version:

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.24
```

Comment: Fixed it for me- I'm on Angular 8.0.0

Comment: this answer did't work for me. I still see same error after running 'npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.900.4'

Comment: @AtifMajeed you should use version 0.803.24, not 0.900.4

Comment: Worked for me but I don't understand why, I didn't update angular. I did `npm audit fix`

Comment: I also started getting this error after `npm audit fix` today. Basically what I understood about `npm audit fix` is that it automatically detect all vulnerable packages and upgrade with fixed versions if available. But it is not supposed to do any breaking upgrade like this automatically. So there must be some mistake from the side of that package maintainer too, that caused npm audit to be unaware of the breaking change.

Comment: Latest version is `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.26` Link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular/v/0.803.26

Comment: There's going to be a lot of projects out there using exactly @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.24 now! XD

Comment: When I Did like this I lost some specific installed packages

Comment: As @aunlead wrote, check the version first. If you are getting a warning like `Your global Angular CLI version (9.1.8) is greater than your local
version (8.3.26). The local Angular CLI version is used.` from the command `ng serve` then the project you've loaded is older than your global version. Translate the local version number (here 8.3.26) into 0.803.36 and then run it with that version number (here `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.26`).

Comment: `npm audit fix` and/or other packages could cause you to get/have different version of `@angular-devkit/build-angular` (refer [Ashot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61320716/9195902) as well). Beside this solution, consider to use [npm-force-resolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions). It can solve such issues.

Comment: Most probably because `@angular-devkit/build-angular` only updates the minor version and not the major version. That would be why npm audit thinks its fine to just update.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and above solution is not working for me. I tried upgrading and downgrading but no luck. Any helping hand please :(

Comment: Hi @AjeetMalviya, you can check my answer below. This one is outdated.

Answer (score 19):

Run also `npm i @angular-builders/custom-webpack@8.4.1 --save`

For me [Occian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60175862/1843460) was not enough, I also had to change `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` from `latest` to `8.4.1`, because it had `build-angular` dependency too. This is how to figure it out:

> npm list @angular-devkit/build-angular
>
> ```
> reports-web-client@0.0.0 C:\projects\2778\reports-web-client
> +-- @angular-builders/custom-webpack@9.1.0
> | `-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.1
> `-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.8
> ```

Which meant, I had 2 versions of the package, and that's why the error would still show up.

Comment: this solution worked and completely solved my issue. however, it leaded me to consider the use of [npm-force-resolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions). with this tool, we don't need to be annoyed with such multiple versions. we can solve it by just having `"resolutions": { "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.8" }` in package.json instead. it can protect this specific version from `npm audit fix` as well.

Answer (score 10):

Personally, the best solution is:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

Why? Because sooner or later, you need to upgrade to Angular 9+ and the other solutions are only to downgrade it.

I was facing the same issue today until I used this solution and this one works perfectly well.

Answer (score 6):

Use below version for current angular version:

`@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.8.9          v6-lts`

`@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.10        v7-lts`

`@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.29       v8-lts`

`@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.13       v9-lts`

`@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.1       v10-lts`

see last current tags version [@angular-devkit/build-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular?activeTab=versions)

Answer (score 5):

This command fixes the situation temporarily:

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.24
```

My Jenkins build requires me to run the **npm audit fix** command to download dependencyes. This command makes the same error appear again.
Anyone have any idea how to make the audit command ignore angula-devkit?

Answer (score 5):

If you use npm audit fix, find the package which you tried to fix and restore to a stable version and be aware with vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3):

i fixed it by open

package.json file

and update on the next line

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.8"
```

then run

> npm i

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it by downgrading `@angular-devkit/build-angular.` version to `0.803.24` as Occian Fumnanya Dia said in his [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60175862/12344311)
If after downgrading the version you still get the same error, try deleting the folder `platforms` and re-run with `ionic cordova run <platform>`. Replace `<platform>` with `android` or `ios`.

It will recreate the folder `plaforms` with new things.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This cmd fixes the problems

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.24
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting the whole node_modules folders, just rename it and try

```
npm install 
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm //for macOS
```

Please find below my angular packages versions -

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.802.0",
"@angular-devkit/core": "8.2.0",
"@angular/animations": "8.2.0",
"@angular/cli": "8.2.0",
"@angular/common": "8.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "8.2.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.0",
"@angular/core": "8.2.0",
```

Comment: Actually deleting the whole node_modules fixed my issue. I had tried other methods suggested in this thread and I still had the error.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience a new module that you are using is designed for angular9 and you should upgrade your imports if possible to:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.9",
 ...
}
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.9",
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install the @angular-devkit/build-angular according to your version
like if you have angular V.8 then try this or find your version and install it according to your angular version.

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.29
```